# compiling dpdk application using cmake with link static libraries

Tags: cmake, dpdk

I am referring to the DPDK example makefile to compile the dpdk application through CMake. The correct compile command should look like

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc-8  -I/usr/local/include -include rte_config.h -march=native -mno-avx512f -g CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/main.c.o -o dpdk_test  -Wl,-Bstatic -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_kvargs -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_bus_pci -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_kvargs -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -ldl -lnuma
```

This is a part of my CMakeLists.txt:

```
#DPDK_INFRA some DPDK base libs
#DPDK_DRIVER some DPDK driver libs
SET(DPDK_LIBS -Wl,-Bstatic ${DPDK_INFRA} -Wl,--whole-archive ${DPDK_DRIVER} -Wl,--no-whole-archive ${DPDK_INFRA} -Wl,-Bdynamic)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${DPDK_LIBS} pthread numa dl)
```

The **DPDK_DRIVER** generated again after -Bdynamic to make the application panic. If I remove them and recompile, it will work normally and get right result.

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-redhat-linux-gcc-8  -I/usr/local/include -include rte_config.h -march=native -mno-avx512f -g CMakeFiles/dpdk_test.dir/main.c.o -o dpdk_test  -Wl,-Bstatic -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_kvargs -Wl,--whole-archive -lrte_bus_pci -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3 -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_kvargs -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -lnuma -ldl **-lrte_bus_pci -lrte_pmd_vmxnet3** -lpthread -lnuma -ldl
```

I hope your answers

Comment: It is much easier to recreate and debug if version of DPDK is shared with the application. if application can not be shared, at least try the steps on DPDK examples (skeleton, l2fwd, helloworld) too

Comment: are there updates from your end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is known bug with DPDK 20.11.1 LTS for the result of `pkg-config`. Since the DPDK version is not mentioned I will have to assume you are using Higher version (> 20.11).

I am able to compile and use DPDK library in 3rd party projects with CMAKE successfully by making the changes as

- In the parent folder

```
+find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
+
+if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
+       pkg_check_modules(DPDK "libdpdk")
+       if (DPDK_FOUND)
+               message(STATUS "found dpdk via pkg-config")
+       endif()
+endif()
```

- Source folder

```
+pkg_check_modules(DPDK "libdpdk")
+if (DPDK_FOUND)
+  add_definitions(${DPDK_CFLAGS})
+  set(MYDPDK_LIBRARIES -Wl,--whole-archive ${DPDK_LIBRARIES} -lpthread -lnuma -ldl -Wl,--no-whole-archive)
+  include_directories(${DPDK_INCLUDE_DIR})
+  link_libraries(${MYDPDK_LIBRARIES})
+  add_definitions(-DHAVE_DPDK)
+endif(DPDK_FOUND)
```

[EDIT-1] based on the comment suggestion

- In the parent folder

```
+find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
+
+if (PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
+       pkg_check_modules(DPDK "libdpdk")
+       if (DPDK_FOUND)
+               message(STATUS "found dpdk via pkg-config")
+       endif()
+endif()
```

- Source folder

```
+pkg_check_modules(DPDK "libdpdk")
+if (DPDK_FOUND)
+  add_definitions(${DPDK_STATIC_CFLAGS})
+  set(MYDPDK_LIBRARIES ${DPDK_STATIC_LDFLAGS})
+  include_directories(${DPDK_INCLUDE_DIR})
+  link_libraries(${MYDPDK_LIBRARIES})
+  add_definitions(-DHAVE_DPDK)
+endif(DPDK_FOUND)
```

Note: Once `pkg_check_modules` finds libdpdk; the static libraries and cflags can be accessed via `LIBDPDK_STATIC_LDFLAGS` and `LIBDPDK_STATIC_CFLAGS`.

Comment: Why not using $DPDK_STATIC_LIBRARIES ?

Comment: @MappaM nothing wrong, the question from the author is for a shared library. Hence answer is shared for the shared library.