# how can I solve the error of adding symbols

Tags: linux, libpcap, dpdk

I'm trying to compile libpcap with DPDK by running this command :
`cmake -DDPDK_DIR=$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET ../ && make -s all && make -s testprogs && make install`

and I got as an output the following error :

`[  4%] Linking C shared library libpcap.so /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.a: error adding symbols: malformed archive collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcap.dir/build.make:513: libpcap.so.1.11.0-PRE-GIT] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:154: CMakeFiles/pcap.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [Makefile:150: all] Error 2`

how can I solve it please ?

Comment: please share the snippet or sample code to reproduce the issue. Please also share the information like 1) OS distro, 2) compiler version, 3) DPDK version, 4) libpcap version

Comment: I recommend to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912482/compiling-dpdk-application-using-cmake-with-link-static-libraries this too