# rte_eth_dev_count_avail() from the DPDK API returns 0 intel x550 ethernet card on linux 5.4.0 dpdk version 19.11.12

Tags: dpdk, dpdk-pmd

built dpdk 19.11.12 from source and i have written an ext app built using these libraries. I use dpdk-devbind to bind a device to igb_uio .
The device i have is an Intel X550. When i run testpmd it seems to recognize the device but int my app rte_eth_dev_count_avail always returns 0

I would belive this has to either do with the way i have built my dpdk library or my app
this is extract of the Makefile i am using to build my app

```
RTE_SDK ?= /usr/local/share/dpdk
RTE_TARGET ?= x86_64-default-linuxapp-gcc

include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.vars.mk

# binary name
APP = myapp

# all source are stored in SRCS-y
SRCS-y := main.c 
WERROR_FLAGS += -Werror

CFLAGS += -O3 -g
CFLAGS += $(WERROR_FLAGS) -Wno-address-of-packed-member
CFLAGS += -Wall

CFLAGS += -pie -fPIE -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -fstack-protector-strong
CFLAGS += -DSTATSD


LDFLAGS += -z relro -z now
LDFLAGS += -ljansson -lrte_pmd_ixgbe
LDLIBS += -lrte_pmd_ixgbe

# disable since libxenstore.so isn't linked properly
#CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_XENVIRT = n
CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_PMD_IXGBE = y
include $(RTE_SDK)/mk/rte.extapp.mk
```

I build my dpdk libraries using this

```
RUN make -C /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ config T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc 
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=n/CONFIG_RTE_BUILD_SHARED_LIB=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=n/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_ETHDEV_DEBUG=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_E1000_DEBUG_RX=n/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_E1000_DEBUG_RX=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_E1000_DEBUG_TX=n/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_E1000_DEBUG_TX=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_DEBUG_RX=n/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_DEBUG_RX=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_DEBUG_TX=n/CONFIG_RTE_LIBRTE_IXGBE_DEBUG_TX=y/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LOG_DP_LEVEL=RTE_LOG_INFO/CONFIG_RTE_LOG_DP_LEVEL=RTE_LOG_DEBUG/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
RUN cd /dpdk/dpdk-stable-${DPDK_VERSION}/ && cat build/.config | sed -e s/CONFIG_RTE_LOG_HISTORY=256/CONFIG_RTE_LOG_HISTORY=2048/g > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out build/.config
```

i can bind to the interfaces using dpdk-devbind and testpmd also seems to identify and be able to bind to these devices

but my app is not able to recognize the devices.
What am i missing here ?

these are the logs `--log-level=8` for EAL logs and I get this output

```
Sep 09 04:56:50  {"timestamp": 1662717410.8821511, "level": "info", "message": "Initialising EAL ..."}
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Detected 64 lcore(s)
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Debug dataplane logs available - lower performance
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Debug dataplane logs available - lower performance
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Probing VFIO support...
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: VFIO support initialized
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: Probing VFIO support...
Sep 09 04:56:50  EAL: VFIO support initialized
```

also adding the -d parameter with the directory where the plugins are located /usr/local/lib/ gives me an error where the plugin is not found
the eal param initialized is

```
--master-lcore 4 -l 4,5,6,7 --log-level 8 -d /usr/local/lib/
```

Sep 09 04:47:29 EAL: Detected 64 lcore(s)
Sep 09 04:47:29 EAL: Detected 2 NUMA nodes
Sep 09 04:47:29 EAL: librte_compressdev.so.0.200: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Sep 09 04:47:29 EAL: FATAL: Cannot init plugins
Sep 09 04:47:29 EAL: Cannot init plugins

```
the librte_compressdev.so.0.200 is present in the path
```

ls -l /usr/local/lib/librte_compressdev.so.0.200
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 38024 Sep  8 23:51 /usr/local/lib/librte_compressdev.so.0.200

Comment: please share EAL arguments used, and `from the logs it looks it is shared library is used`. hence one should use real args option `-d` with PMD library. Please also share the logs with `--log-level=8`

Comment: my eal args are GLB_DIRECTOR_EAL_ARGS="--master-lcore 4 -l 4,5,6,7".  i will try to pass the -d option with the pmd library. and also share the logs with log-level 8

Comment: you can first run `--log-level=8`, then check if the logs shows PMD probe if not run with `-d`

Comment: Based on the output of `log-level=8` it is clear there is no PMD probe. which means application is built with shared library but there is no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set or `in real args -d for appropriate driver is not passed`.

Comment: this is bit confusing, your error is related to `rte_eth_dev_count_avail` and you claim `librte_compressdev.so is present. Since your device is ixgbe PMD should you check or pass `librte_pmd_ixgbe.so`. I can make myself available for live debug. But this looks like configuration issue.

Comment: after checking your LDFLAGS, it seems not right. Can you recheck the same or come for a live debug to fix the same?

Comment: are there any updates from your end?

Comment: Nope still working on it I am now suspecting my build process. I still don't see the probe for ixgbe

Comment: When does a live debug work for you ?

Comment: hey vipin what is wrong wit the LDFLAGS ?  i have tried without the LDLIBS or LDFLAGS directive.

Comment: We can do a live debug let me know how should i set it up

Comment: is the ```-z now ``` something you think it is wrong

Comment: sure this is a google meet link  meet.google.com/skm-tcra-gau. Will wait here

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if it has helped you. This will help others to seek the right answers in future.

Comment: waiting for you to accpet and upvote to close the question as it will help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[based on the live debug]

DPDK 17.11 LTS use `libdpdk.so` and a complete shared library, which makes all the necessary ethdev PMD available. hence using the current makefile, it pans out properly without any issues.

But moving to DPDK 19.11 LTS, `libdpdk.so is no longer availble`. hence one have to manually link either in shared or static libraries properly (as pointed out in comments). For example

```
DPDK_CFLAGS=" -DHAVE_DPDK -I${RTE_SDK}/${RTE_TARGET}/include/ -include ${RTE_SDK}/${RTE_TARGET}/include/rte_config.h "


DPDK_LDFLAGS="-I$RTE_SDK/lib/librte_eal/linux/eal/include \
-DRTE_USE_FUNCTION_VERSIONING \
-I$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/include -include $RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/include/rte_config.h \
-D_GNU_SOURCE  -W -Wall  -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API  \
-L$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/lib -Wl,-lrte_flow_classify -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,-lrte_pipeline -Wl,--no-whole-archive \
-Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,-lrte_table -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,--whole-archive \
-Wl,-lrte_port -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-lrte_pdump -Wl,-lrte_ip_frag -Wl,-lrte_meter \
-Wl,-lrte_fib -Wl,-lrte_rib -Wl,-lrte_lpm -Wl,-lrte_acl -Wl,-lrte_power -Wl,-lrte_kni \
-Wl,-lrte_efd -Wl,-lrte_bpf -Wl,-lrte_ipsec -Wl,--whole-archive -Wl,-lrte_cfgfile -Wl,-lrte_gro \
-Wl,-lrte_gso -Wl,-lrte_hash -Wl,-lrte_member -Wl,-lrte_vhost -Wl,-lrte_kvargs -Wl,-lrte_mbuf \
-Wl,-lrte_net -Wl,-lrte_ethdev -Wl,-lrte_cryptodev -Wl,-lrte_security -Wl,-lrte_compressdev \
-Wl,-lrte_eventdev -Wl,-lrte_timer -Wl,-lrte_mempool -Wl,-lrte_stack -Wl,-lrte_mempool_ring \
-Wl,-lrte_ring -Wl,-lrte_pci -Wl,-lrte_eal -Wl,-lrte_cmdline -Wl,-lrte_reorder -Wl,-lrte_sched \
-Wl,-lrte_rcu -Wl,-lrte_bus_pci -Wl,-lrte_bus_vdev -Wl,-lrte_mempool_bucket -Wl,-lrte_mempool_stack \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_af_packet \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_ixgbe \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_memif \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_null \
-Wl,-lpcap -Wl,-lrte_pmd_ring -Wl,-lrte_pmd_tap -Wl,-lrte_pmd_virtio -Wl,-lrte_bus_vmbus \
-Wl,-lcrypto -Wl,-lrte_pmd_null_crypto -Wl,-lrte_pmd_crypto_scheduler -Wl,-lrte_pmd_virtio_crypto \
-Wl,-lrte_pmd_skeleton_event -Wl,-lrte_pmd_sw_event \
-Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-lrt -Wl,-lm -Wl,-lnuma -Wl,-ldl -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic \
-L$RTE_SDK/examples/l2fwd/build/lib -L$RTE_SDK/$RTE_TARGET/lib -Wl,--as-needed"
```

Since DPDk 19.11 LTS makes uses on `meson-ninja`, my suggestion and recommendation is to make use of `pkg-config` to built the right CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. Please refer [StackOverflow query on using dpdk cmake too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69912482/compiling-dpdk-application-using-cmake-with-link-static-libraries)

Note: recommended to build a custom target folder rather than `make install`, since the built and application run is done in docker.